# Finding maximum on a 3D gam-smoothed surface

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization, gam, mgcv

Given the following example:

```
library(mgcv)

set.seed(2)
dat <- gamSim(2, n = 1000, dist = "normal", scale = 1)
m <- gam(y ~ s(x, z, k = 40), data = dat$data, method = "REML")
fit <- predict(m)
vis.gam(m, se=T, type="response")
```

Is there any way to find peaks and valleys of the smoothed surface and plot it with label(s)? Something similar to the following:

[image: expected output]

Comment: You could modify the vis.gam {mgcv} function so that instead of only plotting, you get the output of the "z" axis. Then you use the x-y-z data to locate which is the highest "z" point for a x and y combination.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by modifying the vis.gam so that it also *prints* the ouput (note that the only thing I changed was "`return(list(m1=m1,m2=m2,z=z))`"  at the end):

```
my.gam.out = function (x, view = NULL, cond = list(), n.grid = 30, too.far = 0, 
                       col = NA, color = "heat", contour.col = NULL, se = -1, type = "link", 
                       plot.type = "persp", zlim = NULL, nCol = 50, ...) 
{
  fac.seq <- function(fac, n.grid) {
    fn <- length(levels(fac))
    gn <- n.grid
    if (fn > gn) 
      mf <- factor(levels(fac))[1:gn]
    else {
      ln <- floor(gn/fn)
      mf <- rep(levels(fac)[fn], gn)
      mf[1:(ln * fn)] <- rep(levels(fac), rep(ln, fn))
      mf <- factor(mf, levels = levels(fac))
    }
    mf
  }
  dnm <- names(list(...))
  v.names <- names(x$var.summary)
  if (is.null(view)) {
    k <- 0
    view <- rep("", 2)
    for (i in 1:length(v.names)) {
      ok <- TRUE
      if (is.matrix(x$var.summary[[i]])) 
        ok <- FALSE
      else if (is.factor(x$var.summary[[i]])) {
        if (length(levels(x$var.summary[[i]])) <= 1) 
          ok <- FALSE
      }
      else {
        if (length(unique(x$var.summary[[i]])) == 1) 
          ok <- FALSE
      }
      if (ok) {
        k <- k + 1
        view[k] <- v.names[i]
      }
      if (k == 2) 
        break
    }
    if (k < 2) 
      stop("Model does not seem to have enough terms to do anything useful")
  }
  else {
    if (sum(view %in% v.names) != 2) 
      stop(gettextf("view variables must be one of %s", 
                    paste(v.names, collapse = ", ")))
    for (i in 1:2) if (!inherits(x$var.summary[[view[i]]], 
                                 c("numeric", "factor"))) 
      stop("Don't know what to do with parametric terms that are not simple numeric or factor variables")
  }
  ok <- TRUE
  for (i in 1:2) if (is.factor(x$var.summary[[view[i]]])) {
    if (length(levels(x$var.summary[[view[i]]])) <= 1) 
      ok <- FALSE
  }
  else {
    if (length(unique(x$var.summary[[view[i]]])) <= 1) 
      ok <- FALSE
  }
  if (!ok) 
    stop(gettextf("View variables must contain more than one value. view = c(%s,%s).", 
                  view[1], view[2]))
  if (is.factor(x$var.summary[[view[1]]])) 
    m1 <- fac.seq(x$var.summary[[view[1]]], n.grid)
  else {
    r1 <- range(x$var.summary[[view[1]]])
    m1 <- seq(r1[1], r1[2], length = n.grid)
  }
  if (is.factor(x$var.summary[[view[2]]])) 
    m2 <- fac.seq(x$var.summary[[view[2]]], n.grid)
  else {
    r2 <- range(x$var.summary[[view[2]]])
    m2 <- seq(r2[1], r2[2], length = n.grid)
  }
  v1 <- rep(m1, n.grid)
  v2 <- rep(m2, rep(n.grid, n.grid))
  newd <- data.frame(matrix(0, n.grid * n.grid, 0))
  for (i in 1:length(x$var.summary)) {
    ma <- cond[[v.names[i]]]
    if (is.null(ma)) {
      ma <- x$var.summary[[i]]
      if (is.numeric(ma)) 
        ma <- ma[2]
    }
    if (is.matrix(x$var.summary[[i]])) 
      newd[[i]] <- matrix(ma, n.grid * n.grid, ncol(x$var.summary[[i]]), 
                          byrow = TRUE)
    else newd[[i]] <- rep(ma, n.grid * n.grid)
  }
  names(newd) <- v.names
  newd[[view[1]]] <- v1
  newd[[view[2]]] <- v2
  if (type == "link") 
    zlab <- paste("linear predictor")
  else if (type == "response") 
    zlab <- type
  else stop("type must be \"link\" or \"response\"")
  fv <- predict.gam(x, newdata = newd, se.fit = TRUE, type = type)
  z <- fv$fit
  if (too.far > 0) {
    ex.tf <- exclude.too.far(v1, v2, x$model[, view[1]], 
                             x$model[, view[2]], dist = too.far)
    fv$se.fit[ex.tf] <- fv$fit[ex.tf] <- NA
  }
  if (is.factor(m1)) {
    m1 <- as.numeric(m1)
    m1 <- seq(min(m1) - 0.5, max(m1) + 0.5, length = n.grid)
  }
  if (is.factor(m2)) {
    m2 <- as.numeric(m2)
    m2 <- seq(min(m1) - 0.5, max(m2) + 0.5, length = n.grid)
  }
  if (se <= 0) {
    old.warn <- options(warn = -1)
    av <- matrix(c(0.5, 0.5, rep(0, n.grid - 1)), n.grid, 
                 n.grid - 1)
    options(old.warn)
    max.z <- max(z, na.rm = TRUE)
    z[is.na(z)] <- max.z * 10000
    z <- matrix(z, n.grid, n.grid)
    surf.col <- t(av) %*% z %*% av
    surf.col[surf.col > max.z * 2] <- NA
    if (!is.null(zlim)) {
      if (length(zlim) != 2 || zlim[1] >= zlim[2]) 
        stop("Something wrong with zlim")
      min.z <- zlim[1]
      max.z <- zlim[2]
    }
    else {
      min.z <- min(fv$fit, na.rm = TRUE)
      max.z <- max(fv$fit, na.rm = TRUE)
    }
    surf.col <- surf.col - min.z
    surf.col <- surf.col/(max.z - min.z)
    surf.col <- round(surf.col * nCol)
    con.col <- 1
    if (color == "heat") {
      pal <- heat.colors(nCol)
      con.col <- 4
    }
    else if (color == "topo") {
      pal <- topo.colors(nCol)
      con.col <- 2
    }
    else if (color == "cm") {
      pal <- cm.colors(nCol)
      con.col <- 1
    }
    else if (color == "terrain") {
      pal <- terrain.colors(nCol)
      con.col <- 2
    }
    else if (color == "gray" || color == "bw") {
      pal <- gray(seq(0.1, 0.9, length = nCol))
      con.col <- 1
    }
    else stop("color scheme not recognised")
    if (is.null(contour.col)) 
      contour.col <- con.col
    surf.col[surf.col < 1] <- 1
    surf.col[surf.col > nCol] <- nCol
    if (is.na(col)) 
      col <- pal[as.array(surf.col)]
    z <- matrix(fv$fit, n.grid, n.grid)
    if (plot.type == "contour") {
      stub <- paste(ifelse("xlab" %in% dnm, "", ",xlab=view[1]"), 
                    ifelse("ylab" %in% dnm, "", ",ylab=view[2]"), 
                    ifelse("main" %in% dnm, "", ",main=zlab"), ",...)", 
                    sep = "")
      if (color != "bw") {
        txt <- paste("image(m1,m2,z,col=pal,zlim=c(min.z,max.z)", 
                     stub, sep = "")
        eval(parse(text = txt))
        txt <- paste("contour(m1,m2,z,col=contour.col,zlim=c(min.z,max.z)", 
                     ifelse("add" %in% dnm, "", ",add=TRUE"), ",...)", 
                     sep = "")
        eval(parse(text = txt))
      }
      else {
        txt <- paste("contour(m1,m2,z,col=1,zlim=c(min.z,max.z)", 
                     stub, sep = "")
        eval(parse(text = txt))
      }
    }
    else {
      stub <- paste(ifelse("xlab" %in% dnm, "", ",xlab=view[1]"), 
                    ifelse("ylab" %in% dnm, "", ",ylab=view[2]"), 
                    ifelse("zlab" %in% dnm, "", ",zlab=zlab"), ",...)", 
                    sep = "")
      if (color == "bw") {
        op <- par(bg = "white")
        txt <- paste("persp(m1,m2,z,col=\"white\",zlim=c(min.z,max.z) ", 
                     stub, sep = "")
        eval(parse(text = txt))
        par(op)
      }
      else {
        txt <- paste("persp(m1,m2,z,col=col,zlim=c(min.z,max.z)", 
                     stub, sep = "")
        eval(parse(text = txt))
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    if (color == "bw" || color == "gray") {
      subs <- paste("grey are +/-", se, "s.e.")
      lo.col <- "gray"
      hi.col <- "gray"
    }
    else {
      subs <- paste("red/green are +/-", se, "s.e.")
      lo.col <- "green"
      hi.col <- "red"
    }
    if (!is.null(zlim)) {
      if (length(zlim) != 2 || zlim[1] >= zlim[2]) 
        stop("Something wrong with zlim")
      min.z <- zlim[1]
      max.z <- zlim[2]
    }
    else {
      max.z <- max(fv$fit + fv$se.fit * se, na.rm = TRUE)
      min.z <- min(fv$fit - fv$se.fit * se, na.rm = TRUE)
      zlim <- c(min.z, max.z)
    }
    z <- fv$fit - fv$se.fit * se
    z <- matrix(z, n.grid, n.grid)
    if (plot.type == "contour") 
      warning("sorry no option for contouring with errors: try plot.gam")
    stub <- paste(ifelse("xlab" %in% dnm, "", ",xlab=view[1]"), 
                  ifelse("ylab" %in% dnm, "", ",ylab=view[2]"), ifelse("zlab" %in% 
                                                                         dnm, "", ",zlab=zlab"), ifelse("sub" %in% dnm, 
                                                                                                        "", ",sub=subs"), ",...)", sep = "")
    txt <- paste("persp(m1,m2,z,col=col,zlim=zlim", ifelse("border" %in% 
                                                             dnm, "", ",border=lo.col"), stub, sep = "")
    eval(parse(text = txt))
    par(new = TRUE)
    z <- fv$fit
    z <- matrix(z, n.grid, n.grid)
    txt <- paste("persp(m1,m2,z,col=col,zlim=zlim", ifelse("border" %in% 
                                                             dnm, "", ",border=\"black\""), stub, sep = "")
    eval(parse(text = txt))
    par(new = TRUE)
    z <- fv$fit + se * fv$se.fit
    z <- matrix(z, n.grid, n.grid)
    txt <- paste("persp(m1,m2,z,col=col,zlim=zlim", ifelse("border" %in% 
                                                             dnm, "", ",border=hi.col"), stub, sep = "")
    eval(parse(text = txt))
  }
  return(list(m1=m1,m2=m2,z=z))
}
```

Then, you can define a function that will give you the position of the max in Z. I've made it so that you click on the image when prompted: you select the bottom left and then the top right to let R search for the maximum in Z and return you the coordinate in X and in Y.

```
isolate.surf = function(dat, #list from the my.gam.out() custom function 
                        mod = NULL,
                        mod.var = c("x1","x2"),
                        variables = c("m1","m2","z"),
                        locator = FALSE,
                        plot=TRUE) {
  # Extract the columns from the list 
  get.df.from.list = data.frame(x = dat[[variables[1]]], y = dat[[variables[2]]])
  get.z = dat[[variables[3]]]
  
  # Instead of providing the values, you can locate them by clicking on the graph 
  if(locator){
    cat("Please, provide 2 points starting from the bottom left corner and top right:")
    var = 2
    par(mfrow = c(1,1))
    vis.gam(mod, se=F,plot.type = "contour", type="response") 
    my.pts = locator(n = var)
    xmin = my.pts$x[1]
    xmax = my.pts$x[2]
    ymin = my.pts$y[1]
    ymax = my.pts$y[2]
  }
  
  # Isolate the location with the user specified x- and y-axis limits
  find.x = which(get.df.from.list$x>xmin & get.df.from.list$x<xmax)
  find.y = which(get.df.from.list$y>ymin & get.df.from.list$y<ymax)
  
  # Subset the vector for each 
  x = get.df.from.list$x[find.x]
  y = get.df.from.list$y[find.y]
  z = get.z[find.x,find.y] 
  
  # Find the maximum value in the subset 
  max.z = max(z, na.rm = TRUE)
  
  # Find the position of the maximum Z value 
  loc.z = which(z == max.z, arr.ind = TRUE)
  # Find the X and Y coordinate in the subsetted dataset 
  x.y.z = c(x[loc.z[1]], y[loc.z[2]])
  
  # More robust: find the location of the max z from the ORIGINAL indicies
  get.df.from.list$x[find.x[loc.z[1]]]
  get.df.from.list$y[find.y[loc.z[2]]]
  get.z[find.x[loc.z[1]],find.y[loc.z[2]]]
  
  # Get the coordinate from the original data 
  find.local.max = data.frame(
    x = get.df.from.list$x[find.x[loc.z[1]]],
    y = get.df.from.list$y[find.y[loc.z[2]]],
    z = get.z[find.x[loc.z[1]],find.y[loc.z[2]]])
  
  if(!is.null(mod)){
    tmp.df = data.frame(x = x.y.z[1], y = x.y.z[2])
    colnames(tmp.df) <- mod.var
    mod.pred.z = predict(mod, newdata = tmp.df, type = "response")
  } else {mod.pred.z = NULL}
  
  
  # Make a visual verification 
  if(plot){
    vis.gam(mod, se=F,plot.type = "contour", type="response") 
    points(tmp.df[1],tmp.df[2], cex = 1,pch = 19)
  }
  
  
  # Get the data out of the function 
  return(list(tmp.df = tmp.df,
              mod.pred.z = mod.pred.z) # X-Y-Z coordinate in a dataframe 
  )
  
}
```

Then just use it with you data:

```
################
library(mgcv)

set.seed(2)
dat <- gamSim(2, n = 1000, dist = "normal", scale = 1)
dat$data$y
m <- gam(y ~ s(x, z, k = 40), data = dat$data, method = "REML")
fit <- predict(m)
vis.gam(m, se=F,plot.type = "contour", type="response") 
mygame = my.gam.out(m, se=F,plot.type = "contour", type="response") 
# you'll need to click on the graph to 'isolate' a peak
isolate.surf(dat = mygame,  mod = m,mod.var = c("x","z"),variables = c("m1","m2","z"),locator = TRUE)
```

The answer:

[image]

Unfortunately, it won't do it for multiple peak. But a small change could be made to let the locator function gather more points.

I don't have the 'valleys' in this function, but it might get you started!